# Typing error on class name in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Just now i purchased an angular2 theme but when i run it after installing npm it is showing error in which the following is one.I just attached the screen shot of it in my vsc. Can anyone please suggest help.

[image: Its a typing error on class names]

my ts.config.json,

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: Has this happened before in any other projects not using this template?

Comment: Could you add `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @peeskillet no it was error with this template only

Comment: Try setting the user settings. First look in the package.json and make sure it's using the latest typescript (I think 2.0.3) right now. Then go to File->preferences->user settings, and add `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` to the json. Maybe also  `"typescript.check.tscVersion": false`.  This is the settings I'm using. You may also need a restart

Comment: My typescript  Version 2.0.6 and my project it is 2.0.0 is that make any sense.

Comment: I don't think it matters. As long as it's at least 2.0. Did you try to change the settings?

Comment: I changed the sttings.json as you said

Comment: Still the error remains ....

Comment: Where should i change in settings.json or defaultsettings  ?

Comment: settings.json. Honestly I used to have this problem all the time (and it was only in projects that didn't have the tsconfig at the root of the project. But after a while (after a few automatic updates from VSCode) it just stopped happening

Comment: k i got some issue like  Error: Can't resolve 'jQuery-Mapael/js/jquery.mapael.js' in '/var/www/html/a2practise/angular2/src/app/dashboard'

Comment: but i didnt have 'jQuery-Mapae in my dashboard folder ,so cloned it into the dashboard folder from github but still the error remains ,can you guess the error